# Stationary header and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, swipe

I want to swipe through these pages as so, but when it happens I want the header panel and the footer to remain stationary. I only want the page content to move when the pages are swiped or changed.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nj3prx5h/

*HTML :*

```
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1 style="text-align:left; margin-left:40px;">Rates</h1>
            <a href="#bars3" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Bars</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <h4 align="center">2015 Rates</h4>           


        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#Rates" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Rates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#StayandPlay">Stay & Play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#MemberSpecials">Specials</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div><!-- /footer -->

        <div data-role="panel" id="bars3" data-theme="a">
            <!-- panel content goes here -->
            <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-outer">
                <li><a href="#Home" data-transition="fade">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#TeeTimes" data-transition="fade">Book Tee Times</a></li>
                <li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false">
                    <h2>Rates</h2>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-shadow="false" data-inset="true" data-corners="false">
                        <li><a href="#Rates" data-transition="fade">2015 Rates</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#StayandPlay" data-transition="fade">Stay & Play</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#MemberSpecials" data-transition="fade">Specials</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#Scorecard" data-transition="fade">Scorecard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ContactUs" data-transition="fade">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /panel -->
    </div><!-- end of Rates page -->

    <!-- ~~~~~ Stay and Play ~~~~~ -->
    <div data-role="page" id="StayandPlay">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1 style="text-align:left; margin-left:40px;">Rates</h1>
            <a href="#bars4" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Bars</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <h4 align="center">Stay & Play</h4>


        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#Rates" >Rates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#StayandPlay" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Stay & Play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#MemberSpecials" >Specials</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div><!-- /footer -->

        <div data-role="panel" id="bars4" data-theme="a">
            <!-- panel content goes here -->
            <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-outer">
                <li><a href="#Home" data-transition="fade">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#TeeTimes" data-transition="fade">Book Tee Times</a></li>
                <li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false">
                    <h2>Rates</h2>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-shadow="false" data-inset="true" data-corners="false">
                        <li><a href="#Rates" data-transition="fade">2015 Rates</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#StayandPlay" data-transition="fade">Stay & Play</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#MemberSpecials" data-transition="fade">Specials</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#Scorecard" data-transition="fade">Scorecard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ContactUs" data-transition="fade">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /panel -->
    </div><!-- end of  Stay and Play page -->

    <!-- ~~~~~ SPECIALS ~~~~~ -->
    <div data-role="page" id="MemberSpecials">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1 style="text-align:left; margin-left:40px;">Rates</h1>
            <a href="#bars5" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Bars</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">

            <h4 align="center">2015 New Member Specials</h4>

        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#Rates">Rates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#StayandPlay">Stay & Play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#MemberSpecials" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Specials</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div><!-- /footer -->

        <div data-role="panel" id="bars5" data-theme="a">
            <!-- panel content goes here -->
            <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-outer">
                <li><a href="#Home" data-transition="fade">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#TeeTimes" data-transition="fade">Book Tee Times</a></li>
                <li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false">
                    <h2>Rates</h2>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-shadow="false" data-inset="true" data-corners="false">
                        <li><a href="#Rates" data-transition="fade">2015 Rates</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#StayandPlay" data-transition="fade">Stay and Play</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#MemberSpecials" data-transition="fade">Specials</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#Scorecard" data-transition="fade">Scorecard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ContactUs" data-transition="fade">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /panel -->
    </div><!-- end of Specials page -->
```

*JS :*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('swipeleft', swipeLeft);
    $(document).on('swiperight', swipeRight);

    function swipeLeft(event) {
        if ($.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('getActivePage').attr('id') === "Rates") {
            $.mobile.changePage("#StayandPlay", {
                transition: "slide"
            });
        } else if ($.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('getActivePage').attr('id') === "StayandPlay") {
            $.mobile.changePage("#MemberSpecials", {
                transition: "slide"
            });
        }
    }

    function swipeRight(event) {
        if ($.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('getActivePage').attr('id') === "MemberSpecials") {
            $.mobile.changePage("#StayandPlay", {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: true
            });
        } else if ($.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('getActivePage').attr('id') === "StayandPlay") {
            $.mobile.changePage("#Rates", {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: true
            });
        }
    }
});
```

How can I do this? I am more worried about the footer as that looks much worse, but if I could get help with both footer and header panel that would be great!